# Continuous function, mapping of a set to itself

Tags: continuity

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be continuous. Any idea on how we can prove that it is not possible for $f$ to map $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$ exactly two-to-one. That is, there is no continuous $f$ as above such that for each $y \in [0,1]$, there are exactly two values $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that

$$y = f(x_1) = f(x_2)$$

Comment: Consider extremas.

Comment: before going to a function, you should know about a relation. if a relation is many-one , that can not be a function.

Comment: @mookid "Extrema" is the plural of "extremum".

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Thank you, but in this question f is assumed to be continuous, correct?

Comment: The linked question in my comment says that if $f$ is two-to-one then it can't be continuous. Both your version and my version are saying the same thing in different words.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh I see what you are saying, helpful hint, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose such a function does exist. It attains its max and min in [0,1].so there exists $x_1, x_2\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=1$ Lets assume $0<x_1<x_2<1$.similarly we can find $0<y_1<y_2<1$ Such that $f(y_1)=f(y_2)=0$. Then by intermediate value property you can find atleast three points $a,b,c$ with $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)$ but this is contradiction.(to be more precise we should split into cases according to the location of $x_i,y_i, i=1,2$ )

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so helpful :)